# Accessing a session-scoped bean inside a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm experimenting with session-scoped beans in Spring 3. I have the following bean definition:

```
<bean id="userInfo" class="net.sandbox.sessionbeans.UserInfo" scope="session" />
```

Here is `net.sandbox.controllers.RegistrationController`, a controller class that needs access to this bean. I've taken out the imports for brevity's sake.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    private UserInfo userInfo;   // This should reference the session-scoped bean

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegForm(Model model) {
        RegistrationForm regForm = new RegistrationForm();
        model.addAttribute("regform", regForm);
        return "regform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(@Valid RegistrationForm regForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "regform";
        }

        userInfo.setUserName(regForm.getFirstName());
        model.addAttribute("regform", regForm);
        return "regsuccess";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to automatically tie the session-scoped bean I defined to the member variable  `private UserInfo userInfo` in `RegistrationController`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - see [section 3.4.5.4 of the Spring manual, "Scoped beans as dependencies"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection).

Briefly, you can ask Spring to wrap your session-scoped bean in a singleton proxy, which looks up the correct session when you invoke a method on the scoped bean. This is called a "scoped proxy", and uses the `<aop:scoped-proxy>` config macro.  You can then inject the reference as you would any other (e.g. `<property>`, or `@Autowired`). See the above link for details.

Comment: I tried applying this technique. I put `<aop:scoped-proxy />` inside the bean definition and I `@Autowired`'d `private UserInfo userInfo`. It seems to work, but for some reason the bean's setter function isn't executed properly... http://i.imgur.com/zkxVA.png

Comment: @Pieter Any progress on the above ?, i am facing the same issue

Comment: @Sudarshan I made this site as part of a short-term school project a while ago and I'm no longer working on it. Sorry! Good luck finding a solution though.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring creates a proxy by implementing an interface at run-time.  So, the only methods available on the proxy are those defined in any interfaces UserInfo implements  (if any).  You may have to create a suitable interface that includes the setUserName() method.

Alternatively, you will need to force a CGI based proxy (the proxy is a sub-class of your class created at run-time so it doesn't need an interface).  Specify:

```
<bean id="userInfo" class="net.sandbox.sessionbeans.UserInfo" scope="session" >
   <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

About this comment:

> I tried applying this technique. I put
>    inside the bean
>   definition and I @Autowired'd private
>   UserInfo userInfo. It seems to work,
>   but for some reason the bean's setter
>   function isn't executed properly...
>   i.imgur.com/zkxVA.png – Pieter 1 hour
>   ago

If you use interface-based proxies, the setter method is not available on the Proxy unless the interface has the setter method.

Comment: Interface-based proxies? I'm new to Spring, Java web development and design patterns, so I'm afraid that I don't know what you're describing. I only know that I want to access and update the 'userInfo` bean inside that controller class. My apologies if that's less than helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like XML, you can also use [`ObjectFactory<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html) like this :

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    private final ObjectFactory<MySessionScopedComponent> OFSession;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(ObjectFactory<MySessionScopedComponent> OFSession) {
        this.OFSession = OFSession;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myMethod () {
        MySessionScopedComponent sessionBean = OFSession.getObject();
        // Do some stuff
        return bean.myValue();
    }
}
```

Note: Tested with Spring Boot 1.5.6 (Spring 4.3)